# MultiValueDictKeyError: GET works, POST does not. Why?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I’m trying to process files uploaded by the user in Django 2.2 and it appears GET requests are working however POST is throwing  MultiValueDictKeyError.

I’m following Vitor Freitas’ glorious [Django File Upload Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zx09vcYq1oc) on YouTube.

At roughly 5 minutes in, the instructor begins adding the POST request method. My project is slightly different in terms of some of the names and other apps I am working with.  I am running Django 2.2 in my local dev environment and have no intention of deploying this project in the future.

I've meticulously checked checked every line several times.

When I swap out "POST" for "GET" the MultiValueDictKeyError error disappears and the webpage runs without an error but my Django shell does not print file name and size, as I am expecting.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class Home(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
        print(uploaded_file.name)
        print(uploaded_file.size)
    return render(request, 'upload.html')
```

My upload.html:

```
{% block content %}

    <h1> Eureka! </h1>

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="document">
        <button type="submit">Upload file</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
# from . import views
from posts.views import *
from redactors.views import *
from counters.views import *
from AllAbove.views import *
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from uploads.views import *

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('', home, name='home'),
   path('result/', result, name='result'),
   path('seth/', counters, name='seth'),
   path('uploads/', upload, name='upload'),
   #path('james/', post_details, name='james'),
   path('maggie/', maggie_post_details, name='maggie'),
   path('AllAbove/', all_above, name='AllAbove'),
   re_path(r'^posts/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$', post_details, name='james'),
   path('simon/', redactors, name='simon'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL,
```

I am expecting the template to prompt the user to upload a file (like an image) and then in the Django shell show the file name and size. Instead, I am receiving the MultiValueDictKeyError. The error indicates there is an issue with the ‘document’ name somewhere. As far as I can tell, 'document' is referenced properly inside both the template and in views.py

Here is the error and traceback in full:

> Request Method:   POST
>   Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/
>   Django Version:   2.2
>   Exception Type:   MultiValueDictKeyError
>   Exception Value:'document'
>   Exception Location:   /home//dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact_Iter2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py in **getitem**, line 80
>   Python Executable:    /home//dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact_Iter2/venv/bin/python3
>   Python Version:   3.7.3
>   Python Path:
>   ['/home//dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact_Iter2',
>    '/home//dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact_Iter2/venv/lib/python37.zip',
>    '/home//dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact_Iter2/venv/lib/python3.7',
>   '/home//dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact_Iter2/venv/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
>    '/usr/lib64/python3.7',
>    '/usr/lib/python3.7',
>   '/home//dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact_Iter2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
>   Server time:    Fri, 19 Jul 2019 16:56:46 +0000

And:

> $ python3 manage.py runserver
>   Watching for file changes with StatReloader
>   Performing system checks...
>   System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
>   July 19, 2019 - 16:57:53
>   Django version 2.2, using settings 'CC_Redact_Iter2.settings'
>   Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>   Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
>   Internal Server Error: /uploads/
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home//dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact_Iter2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 78, in **getitem**
>       list_ = super().**getitem**(key)
>   KeyError: 'document'
>   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home//dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact_Iter2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)
>     File "/home//dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact_Iter2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>     File "/home//dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact_Iter2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>     File "/home//dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact_Iter2/uploads/views.py", line 9, in upload
>       uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
>     File "/home//dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact_Iter2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 80, in **getitem**
>       raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
>   django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'document'
>   [19/Jul/2019 16:57:57] "POST /uploads/ HTTP/1.1" 500 79510

Comment: Note that request.FILES will only contain data if the request method was POST and the that posted the request has the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data". Otherwise, request.FILES will be empty.

Comment: ref this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try once using the the MultiValueDict's `get()` method to get the data from `request` dictionary.

```
uploaded_file = request.FILES.get('document', None)
```

Comment: This resolves the issue! Thank you Astik! I'm wondering why the instructor's video does not include this necessary method and `None` parameter. The only thing I can think of is that I'm building this app on top of Django 2.2 and the instructor is using 2.1. Is this a change that the Django developers may have made from 2.1 > 2.2?

Comment: @Drone4four, Glad that it helped. You can mark the answer as selected if, it has resolved your issue. Thanks.